# Declare variable for shared procedure inside procedure instead Imports statement

Tags: vb.net

I'm using an imports statement to access shared constants and shared procedures just to shorten things a bit.

```
Imports vList = Helper.Stores.Departments.FruitList
```

But what I'd really like to do is declare it inside the procedure:

```
Dim vList as Helper.Stores.Departments.FruitList
```

Of course I get the warning: `Access of shared member, constant member, enum member or nested type through an instance; qualifying expression will not be evaluated.` when I try to use it like that.

Is there a way to do something like this inside the procedure without using the imports statement?

Comment: _"But what I'd really like to do is declare it inside the procedure"_ Any particular reason?

Comment: @JamesThorpe As already mentioned: "to shorten things a bit".

Comment: I suppose there might be a way with a delegate sub, but don't think it would be worth the effort.

Comment: But you can shorten it using the `Imports` - I wondered why you wanted to do it in the procedure rather than just using the `Imports` route?

Comment: @JamesThorpe  The reason I'd like it inside the procedure is that seems a more natural place for it to be. It's actually fine using Imports. Just thought I might learn something and it seems I have if aleroot is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know you can only create an alias of this kind with an import statement as you already done. 
The thing that you can do inside a procedure is creating variables  using the fully qualified name for the class.

Take a look at the MSDN documentation about [Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt9tafza.aspx) for more information.